# mouseenter clearInterval() in vanila JS carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an infinity carousel with 3 slides. I was able to separate functions with help. I want the function slider to stop when I put my mouse on this slide, and when I take my mouse off, it will work again.

`ClearInterval` was used through `addEventListner`, but it did not work. `ClearInterval (movement)` also did not work within the movement function.

The last function I tested was this. What should I do to implement this function? `clearInterval(slider)` is not working

```js
function slider() {
        let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
            slider = document.querySelector(".slider"),
            last = slider.lastElementChild,
            first = slider.firstElementChild,
            btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

        slider.insertBefore(last, first);

        btn.forEach(btn => {
            btn.addEventListener("click", movement);
        });

        setInterval(function () {
            movement({
                target: {
                    id: "next"
                }
            });
        }, 8000);

        function movement(e) {
            slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
            last = slider.lastElementChild;
            first = slider.firstElementChild;

            const activeSlide = document.querySelector(".active");

            if (e.target.id === "next") {
                slider.insertBefore(first, last.nextSibling);

                activeSlide.classList.remove("active");
                activeSlide.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");

            } else {
                slider.insertBefore(last, first);
                activeSlide.classList.remove("active");
                activeSlide.previousElementSibling.classList.add("active");
            }

        }

    }
    slider();

    let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].mouseenter(function () {
            clearInterval(slider);
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                movement({
                    target: {
                        id: "next"
                    }
                });
            }, 8000);
        })
    }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.slide.active {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.slide.active~.slide {
  -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.slide {
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: aliceblue;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider__wrapper">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide active">
      <h3>Slide One</h3>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <h3>Slide Two</h3>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <h3>Slide Three</h3>
      <p>1234</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="prev" class="btn">Prev</button>
  <button id="next" class="btn">Next</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Not at a computer but I feel as though you mouse events should have `.addEventListener` in there somewhere. `slides[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {.....`

Comment: Yes I tried it. but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the working fine as you expected.clearInterval function needs the value that is returned by setInterval, another problem is defining the "movement" function in parallel to the slider function so that it can be accessed from mouseleave event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }

        .slider {
        position: relative;
        width: 100vw;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 120px;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        }

        .slide {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease;
        transition: 0.6s ease;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
        transform: translate(-100%, 0);
        }

        .slide.active {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        }

        .slide.active~.slide {
        -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
        transform: translate(100%, 0);
        }

        * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
        text-align: center;
        }

        .slide {
        background: #222;
        color: white;
        padding: 30px;
        }

        button {
        margin-top: 20px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        background: aliceblue;
        color: #333;
        padding: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        }        
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="slider__wrapper">
            <div class="slider">
              <div class="slide active">
                <h3>Slide One</h3>
                <p>test</p>
              </div>
              <div class="slide">
                <h3>Slide Two</h3>
                <p>test</p>
              </div>
              <div class="slide">
                <h3>Slide Three</h3>
                <p>1234</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          
            <button id="prev" class="btn">Prev</button>
            <button id="next" class="btn">Next</button>
          </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var sliderInterval = '';
        function movement(e) {
            slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
            last = slider.lastElementChild;
            first = slider.firstElementChild;

            const activeSlide = document.querySelector(".active");

            if (e.target.id === "next") {
                slider.insertBefore(first, last.nextSibling);

                activeSlide.classList.remove("active");
                activeSlide.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");

            } else {
                slider.insertBefore(last, first);
                activeSlide.classList.remove("active");
                activeSlide.previousElementSibling.classList.add("active");
            }
        }
        function slider() {
        let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
            slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
        
        console.log("slider=========",slider);

        let last = slider.lastElementChild,
            first = slider.firstElementChild,
            btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

        slider.insertBefore(last, first);

        btn.forEach(btn => {
            btn.addEventListener("click", movement);
        });

        sliderInterval = setInterval(function () {
            movement({
                target: {
                    id: "next"
                }
            });
        }, 1000);


    }
    slider();

    let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        console.log("slides[i]=========",slides[i]);
        slides[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
            console.log("on mouseenter");
            clearInterval(sliderInterval);
        })
        slides[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
            sliderInterval = setInterval(function () {
                movement({
                    target: {
                        id: "next"
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);
        })
    }
    </script>
</html>
```